# What's the difference between $.proxy and the native js 'call' / 'apply'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I believe they both allow you to control the value of 'this', but beyond that, I'm a little unclear and Google/SO isn't helping much so far. Any clarification appreciated. I did find this, but I'm skeptical that it tells the whole story:

> "When I first learned about jQuery's proxy() method, I thought it was
>   a little silly; after all, Javascript already has call() and apply()
>   methods for changing execution context. But, once you realize that
>   jQuery's proxy() method allows you to easily bind() and unbind() event
>   handlers regardless of context, it becomes obvious just how powerful
>   this method is.

Comment: Helpful search terms for Google-fu: JavaScript execution context.

Comment: A lot of jQuery stuff is completely pointless. The fact that many people think it's good to use `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `this.id`, for instant. I haven't looked at `$.proxy`, but it's entirely possible that it's just the same: redundant and pointless.

Comment: @Kolink it is the thing as you writing a function that returns a function that returns apply. Almost every library out there has this method.

Comment: [`.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) is actually a polyfill for [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (as in "creating a new function bound to a given context"). `apply` is just the means to accomplish this. So comparing `.proxy` to `apply`/`call` does not make sense.

Comment: A better comparison is between `$.proxy()` and the `.bind()` API in newer browsers. (Not to be confused with jQuery's `.bind()`, which is now deprecated in favor of `.on()` anyway.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

call/apply are a single-shot invocation.   $.proxy creates a new function permanently bound to something:

```
fn.call(foo);  //call once

var otherFn = $.proxy(fn, foo);  // you can call it again later

var otherOtherFn = fn.bind(foo);  // ES5 standard way
```

As a simplification (*very simplified*), `$.proxy` is creating a new function that calls `call`:

```
$.proxy = function(fn, newThis) {
    return function() {
        fn.call(newThis);
    }
}
```

It is analogous to ES5's [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the jQuery source:

```
proxy: function( fn, context ) {
    var tmp, args, proxy;

    if ( typeof context === "string" ) {
        tmp = fn[ context ];
        context = fn;
        fn = tmp;
    }

    // Quick check to determine if target is callable, in the spec
    // this throws a TypeError, but we will just return undefined.
    if ( !jQuery.isFunction( fn ) ) {
        return undefined;
    }

    // Simulated bind
    args = core_slice.call( arguments, 2 );
    proxy = function() {
        return fn.apply( context || this, args.concat( core_slice.call( arguments ) ) );
    };

    // Set the guid of unique handler to the same of original handler, so it can be removed
    proxy.guid = fn.guid = fn.guid || jQuery.guid++;

    return proxy;
},
```

If you remove the caching code and make it a little shorter, you essentially get `.apply()` (I think I translated the slicing code correctly):

```
proxy: function(fn, context) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);

    return function() {
        return fn.apply(context || this, args.concat([].slice.call(arguments)));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.proxy` you can call on a function and the function it returns will ALWAYS have a particular context. That means that if you ran

```
$.proxy(function() {console.log(this.val)}, {val: 1}).call({val: 2});
```

It would log `1` because the function is always bound to the object that was initially passed to `proxy`